# Как вывести количество связанных моделей в GridView?

Tags: yii2

У меня есть модель `Authors`, у этой модели есть связь с моделями `Books`. Я хотел бы вывести количество этих моделей (`Books`) в `GridView`.

Как это сделать?

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\models\SearchAuthor */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Authors';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="author-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create author', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Create book', ['books/create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Library', ['books/index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'name',
            'patronymic',
            'surname',
            'created_at',
            //'updated_at',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```php
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

    'id',
    'name',
    'patronymic',
    'surname',
    'created_at',
    //'updated_at',
    [
        'label'=>'Количество Books',      
        'value' => function($authors) {
            return $authors->getBooks()->count();
        }
    ],

    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
```